# macro for arranging data into a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have List of files with product price data in it, I converted pdf files to xlsx format while converting data is dislocated, the price data is dispersed in J,K,L columns, is there a macro in excel that can look at $ symbol and arrange all price data into K column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with data like:

[image]

Running this macro:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim J As Range, L As Range, r As Range
    Set J = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("J:J"))
    Set L = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("L:L"))

    For Each r In J
        If Left(r.Text, 1) = "$" Then
            r.Copy r.Offset(0, 1)
            r.Clear
        End If
    Next r

    For Each r In L
        If Left(r.Text, 1) = "$" Then
            r.Copy r.Offset(0, -1)
            r.Clear
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]